# distinct and Over partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i am working on a query in bigquery and i have the following problem.
The query I have is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (concat(rut,created_at)),*,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY rut ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS ranking 
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(created_at) <= "2020-12-03" 
order by rut,ranking
```

the problem is that the "DISCINT" does not eliminate the duplicate data, instead if I eliminate the OVER PARTITION and leave the query as follows, if it eliminates the repeated data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (concat(rut,created_at)) ,*
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(created_at) <= "2020-12-03" 
order by rut
```

clearly it is a problem of how the discint and the OVER PARTITION work, but I can't find a solution

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The query doesn't really make sense.  `select *` with `distinct` is probably not going to remove any rows.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is unclear what the purpose of your query is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this :

```
select * ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY rut ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS ranking  
from (
SELECT DISTINCT (concat(rut,created_at)),*
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(created_at) <= "2020-12-03" 
) tt
order by rut,ranking
```